# Calculate If it's been less or more than 24 Hours using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate the times between two set times (Cron job run 1 Hour, every Hour).

E.G:

2:18 PM on 20/06/2012
3:00 PM on 21/06/2012 * Cron Job Runs,  More than 24 Hours

How would I calculate this in PHP to do a task that I will develop later.

Script I've attempted:

```
define("SECONDS_PER_HOUR", 60*60);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Calculate the start time
    $str = $row['openTime'] . " " . $row['openDate'];

    $startdatetime = strtotime($str);

    $enddatetime = time();

    // calculate the difference in seconds.

    $difference =  $enddatetime - $startdatetime;

    $hoursDiff = $difference / SECONDS_PER_HOUR;

    $minutesDiffRemainder = $difference % SECONDS_PER_HOUR;

    echo $row['ticketID'] . ": " . $hoursDiff . "h " . $minutesDiffRemainder . "m<br />";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: end result:MFT-252224: 74.5166666667h 1860m
MFT-768337: 18.4333333333h 1560m
MFT-848286: -7.81666666667h -2940m
MFT-70960: -0.0075h -27m
MFT-543912: -0.0075h -27m
MFT-512905: -0.0075h -27m
MFT-496896: -0.0075h -27m
MFT-879190: -0.0075h -27m

Comment: Kris, I edited your code a little, use the  `date_default_timezone_set` early on top as it's configuration. Then first format the string, then run `strtotime`. And the second time you could have spared by just using `time()`. Now the only thing left is to get the difference between two UNIX timestamps which has been asked before an a little search should reveal it quickly.

Comment: I highly suggest looking into this function, too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @hakre: Is this some newfangled way to answer questions? Just edit the actual question and put your answer there?

Comment: @lanzz: I suggest you revisit the edit, I did not change how the code behaves, I just shortened it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered actually doing a query that does what you need and not pull all data and doing the comparison in PHP? You could do

`SELECT * from TICKETS WHERE DATE_ADD(open time, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > CURTIME();`

From reading your code, I'd assume you need to make the `opentime` field is a timestamp, containing both date and time. But that is the sensible choice in most cases, anyway.

Comment: SELECT * from TICKETS WHERE DATE_ADD(open time, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > CURTIME(); 

By using this, what should my input be like as i have date() or should I let MySQL do it automatically?

Comment: Well, if it makes sense to not set the date in your application, you can just use CURTIME() (or NOW()) on inserting. This will take care of the details; you could even have a column default to that.

Be aware that this also has the added benefit of comparing timestamps from the same system: you're always operating at the time of the database. More often than not, the time-of-day of the systems involved is similar enough, but there might be times when they drift apart. Then the 24 hours are compared to the 'right' value (timestamp).